# Show that $(\frac{n}{n^{2}+1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}^{+})$ is a decreasing sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

would anyone please explain to me why the inequality 1

[image]

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: I don't see how the inequality 1<n^2+n makes sense of a_n+1 < a_n. @Camille

Comment: @Tmm It's written in the very next line. 'Since $n \ge 1$, we know that [..]'

Comment: You have $n^2 + n - 1 > 0$ which is true for $n\geq 1$ (look at the quadratic graph or work out the roots). This is equivalent to $\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$, which is equivalent to the original inequality $a_{n+1} < a_n$. Think about it like working backwards.

Comment: @ Stefan how does n≥1 tells the story of the decreasing sequence? I guess I still do not fully understand the logic and the purpose of the inequality.

Comment: I downvoted this because you didn't use http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @ Camille I understand the algebra, but still I couldn't see the connection. I know $n^2+1-1>0$ is equivalent to the original inequality, but how does this help with the proof?

Comment: @Tmm a function is decreasing if whenever $x<y$ then $f(x)\ge f(y)$. A sequence of the kind $(a_n)$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to some set, generally $\Bbb R$. Then if $(a_n)$ is decreasing mean that whenever $n<n+m$ then $a_n\ge a_{n+m}$.

Comment: @ Masacroso thanks, I got that, but I still have difficulty in making the connection why $1<n^2+n$ could lead us to $a_n+1<a_n$ I guess I have some lack of knowledge on inequality. If the two inequalities above are equivalent, does it mean the LHS > RHS from the origin $\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+1}< \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ still holds? if that is the case, I think I get it then. But I am not sure.

Comment: May I ask what book are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to clarify the question. What we do in a proof is

1. Stablish an hypothesis (or more than one).
2. Test if the hypothesis, following the rules of mathematics and mathematical logic, is true or false.

Then we have defined the sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}$. Then our hypothesis to test is: it is the sequence $(a_n)$ decreasing? If $(a_n)$ would be decreasing then it must be true that $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, by the definition of a decreasing function.

Observe that, as we said before, $a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^2+1}$. Then we write explicitly the inequality $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$ i.e.

$$\frac{n}{n^2+1}\ge \frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^2+1}$$

Now, following the rules of mathematics we want to see if the above inequality is true. Then we start to do some algebra over the expression to simplify it and see, in a clear way, if the above inequality is true or false.

If the inequality is true then we proved that the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing. I hope you see now clear.

Comment: @ Masacroso excellent and clear, exactly what I need. thanks so much!

Comment: @Tmm Im happy that you see it! I had the same kind of confusions some years ago when started with mathematics!

Comment: @ Masacroso I appreciate your help and compassion, since like only people has similar experience could relate well.In my opinion, it doesn't mean a person is slow when he could not understand something immediately, it must be because a small missing piece has not be found yet in his or her brain. And you just put that missing piece in me and now the door is opened instantly, this is really great.  I will quit being philosophical now, but must say thank you again for your effort. Now, I feel motivated all over again. take care.

Answer (score 0):

*"I don't see how the inequality $1<n^2+n$ makes sense of $a_{n+1}< a_n$"*,

*"I still have difficulty in making the connection why $1<n^2+n$
could lead us to $a_{n+1}< a_n$"*

More succintly and better suited than the answer you accepted with such enthusiasm: the key to overcome your difficulty was to *follow backwards the equivalences* of your text. It seems the precise point you were missing was the meaning of these $\iff$ signs. The useful direction of these signs, in that proof, is the reverse one: $\impliedby.$